# Watir and Cucumber unable to run on win xp

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

I just download an example of cucumber from http://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/downloads,

and install ruby, watir and cucumber. but I dont know how to run it, I cant found any example for windows.

thanks,

Dani.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cucumber and Watir 101](http://vimeo.com/2871256)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another link to a video presentation on the topic. http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=470645360297935233#

Answer (score 0):

The video is helpfull however to run watir+cucumber,It's requers 4 installation
1. ruby
2. watir
3. cucumber
4. rspec

Comment: And the problem is? If you want to use Watir, you have to install Ruby first (Watir is just a Ruby library). Not sure if you need to install RSpec to use Cucumber.